# Could'nt connect to jboss fuse server to create a fabric in shell tab

Tags: jbossfuse

I have installed JBOSS developer studio 8.1.0 and also I have installed Jboss developer stack integration plugins for JBOSS FUSE developement.

Here the problem arises.To access the JBOSS fuse console I have to create a user in shell tab by connecting the FUSE SERVER.But whenever I enter the server credentials,it displays as SSH client error(Error connecting to the local host).can connect to the JBOSS FUSE console,but to access it I have to create a user name and password in shell tab.

ERROR:

```
Error connecting jboss.4iapps.local:8101 : SSH client error: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Session has timed out waiting for authentication after 120000 ms.
```

NOTE:I have already uncommented the admin user from the user.properties file and also chaned the IP in org.apache.karaf.management file.

Please help me regarding this.

Regards,
Janaarthanan